# How to justify differentiating an asymptotic series in WKB method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, mathematical-physics, perturbation-theory, formal-power-series

Given a second-order linear ordinary differential equation,
\begin{equation}
\epsilon^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = Q(x) y(x),
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation}
where $\epsilon$ is regarded as a small positive number,
a typical explanation of the WKB method (e.g. Ch. 10 of Bender and Orszag, Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers, 1978) starts with writing $y(x)$ as
\begin{equation}
y(x) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{\delta}S(x,\delta)\right),
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation} 
and assuming that $S(x,\delta)$ has an asymptotic series in $\delta$,
\begin{align}
S(x,\delta) \sim& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \delta^n S_n(x) &
\text{ as } \delta\rightarrow&0+.
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}
Then, by substituting eqs. (\ref{2}) and (\ref{3}) into eq. (\ref{1}) and dividing both sides by $\exp(S/\delta)$, it is claimed that
\begin{align}
\frac{\epsilon^2}{\delta^2} 
\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \delta^n \frac{d S_n}{dx}\right]^2
+\frac{\epsilon^2}{\delta}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \delta^n \frac{d^2 S_n}{dx^2}
\sim& Q(x) &
\text{ as } \delta\rightarrow&0+.
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align}
From here, the argument proceeds that we can set $\delta = \epsilon$ from dominant balance, and that we can equate the like powers of $\epsilon$ on both sides to yield differential equations for the coefficient functions $\{S_n(x)\}$ as
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{dS_0}{dx}\right)^2 =& Q(x), 
\tag{5}\label{5}\\
2 \frac{dS_0}{dx}\frac{dS_1}{dx}+\frac{d^2S_0}{dx^2}=&0,
\tag{6}\label{6}\\
\dots
\end{align}
and these equations are solved one after another.

Here is my question. How is it justified to differentiate the asymptotic series in eq. (\ref{3}) to derive eq. (\ref{4})?

I wondered that maybe we can use the fact that $y(x)$ is a solution of eq. (\ref{1}) in some way, but I don't find a way so far.

I read that the derivatives of both sides of an asymptotic relation does not always construct another asymptotic relation, and I guess that even if 
\begin{align}
f(x,\epsilon)\sim& g_0(x) + g_1(x) \epsilon + g_2(x) \epsilon^2 +\cdots&
\text{ as } \epsilon\rightarrow& 0,
\tag{7}\label{7}
\end{align} 
uniformly in some domain of $x$, it does not necessarily follow that 
\begin{align}
\frac{df}{dx}(x,\epsilon) 
\sim& \frac{dg_0}{dx}(x) 
+ \frac{dg_1}{dx}(x)\epsilon + \frac{dg_2}{dx}(x) \epsilon^2 +\cdots&
\text{ as }\epsilon \rightarrow& 0.
\tag{8}\label{8}
\end{align}
Or, does it follow (under some conditions)?

Comment: Instead of a book of 1978, not easily accessible, it might be better to indicate web sites such as ( http://math.arizona.edu/~meissen/docs/asymptotics.pdf) or (http://www.physicspages.com/2014/06/27/wkb-approximation/)

Answer (score 2):

I am answering to my own question while waiting for more answers and comments.

To keep assumption minimum, I think the right thing to assume is that $\partial S/\partial x$, rather than $S$ itself, has an asymptotic expansion. Then, we are allowed to integrate this asymptotic expansion term by term, yielding the asymptotic expansion of $S$. Furthermore, we can justify differentiating the asymptotic expansion of $\partial S/\partial x$ term by term to yield the asymptotic expansion of $\partial^2 S/\partial x^2$, which we need for solving the differential equation, using the Ricatti equation to be satisfied by $\partial S/\partial x$.

So, let me explain this idea in more detail. As wrote in the original question, we solve the ordinary differential equation,
\begin{equation}
\epsilon^2 \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = Q(x) y(x).
\tag{1}\label{1a}
\end{equation}
Note that the solution $y$ depends on the parameter $\epsilon$ as well as the independent variable $x$ of the differential equation.
Let us transform the dependent variable from $y$ to $S$ by
\begin{equation}
y(x,\epsilon) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}S(x,\epsilon)\right).
\tag{2}\label{2a}
\end{equation} 
By substituting eq. (\ref{2a}) into eq. (\ref{1a}), we obtain the differential equation to be satisfied by $S$ as
\begin{equation}
\left[\frac{\partial S}{\partial x}\right]^2 
+\epsilon \frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial x^2}
= Q(x). 
\tag{3}\label{3a}
\end{equation} 
By introducing a notation,
\begin{equation}
u(x,\epsilon) = \frac{\partial S}{\partial x}(x,\epsilon),
\tag{4}\label{4a}
\end{equation}
eq. (\ref{3a}) can be written as 
\begin{equation}
\epsilon \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + u^2 = Q(x).
\tag{5}\label{5a}
\end{equation}
This is the Ricatti equation for $u$.

Now let us make an assumption that
$u(x,\epsilon)$ has a uniform asymptotic power series 
in some domain $D$ of $x$
as $\epsilon$ approaches zero with $\epsilon >0$, i.e.,
\begin{align}
u(x,\epsilon) \sim& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} u_n(x) \epsilon^n &
\text{ as } \epsilon\rightarrow&0+&
\text{ uniformly for } x\in D.
\tag{6}\label{6a}
\end{align}
We first demonstrate that 
the asymptotic expansion of $\partial u/\partial x$ (which is equal to $\partial^2 S/\partial x^2$) is in the form obtained by differentiating eq. (\ref{6a}) term by term.

From the Ricatti equation (\ref{4a}),
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} 
= -\frac{1}{\epsilon} [u(x,\epsilon)]^2 +\frac{1}{\epsilon} Q(x),
\tag{7}\label{7a}
\end{equation}
and from the assumption (\ref{6a}), $u^2$ also has the asymptotic power series,
\begin{align}
[u(x,\epsilon)]^2 \sim& \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} U_k(x) \epsilon^k,&
\text{ as } \epsilon\rightarrow&0+,
\tag{8}\label{8a}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
U_k(x) =& \sum_{n=0}^k u_n(x) u_{k-n}(x),&
k=&0,1,2,\cdots.
\tag{9}\label{9}
\end{align}
From eqs. (\ref{7a}) and (\ref{8a}), it follows that $\partial u/\partial x$ has an asymptotic expansion,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,\epsilon) 
\sim& \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} v_k(x) \epsilon^{k-1} &
\text{ as } \epsilon\rightarrow&0+,
\tag{10}\label{10}
\end{align}
where
\begin{equation}
v_0(x) = -U_0(x) +Q(x) = -[u_0(x)]^2 + Q(x),
\tag{11}\label{11}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{align}
v_k(x) =& U_k(x), & k=& 1,2,3,\dots.
\tag{12}\label{12}
\end{align}

Note that we are allowed to integrate an asymptotic expansion term by term. That is, from eq. (\ref{10}) it follows that
for any $a$ and $b$ in $D$, 
\begin{align}
\int_a^b dx \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} 
=u(b,\epsilon)-u(a,\epsilon)
\sim& \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left[\int_a^b dx v_k(x)\right] \epsilon^{k-1},&
\text{ as } \epsilon\rightarrow&0+.
\tag{13}\label{13}
\end{align}
Note also that we are allowed to sum two asymptotic expansions, and from eq. (\ref{6a}) it follows that 
\begin{align}
u(b,\epsilon) - u(a,\epsilon)
\sim& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [u_n(b)-u_n(a)] \epsilon^n &
\text{ as } \epsilon\rightarrow&0+.
\tag{14}\label{14}
\end{align}
Since an asymptotic expansion of a function 
with a given sequence of gauge functions is unique, 
the expansion coefficients in eqs. (\ref{13}) and (\ref{14}) must agree for each power of $\epsilon$.
Especially, the coefficient for the $\epsilon^{-1}$ term in eq. (\ref{13}) must vanish, i.e.,
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b dx v_0(x) =0,
\tag{15}\label{15}
\end{equation}
for all $a$ and $b$ in $D$.
This means that
\begin{equation}
v_0(x) = 0,
\tag{16}\label{16}
\end{equation}
From the comparison of the $\epsilon^n$ ($n\geq 0$) terms between eq. (\ref{13}) and eq. (\ref{14}), 
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b dx v_{n+1}(x) = u_n(b) - u_n(a),
\tag{17}\label{17}
\end{equation}
for all $a$ and $b$ in $D$.
This means that 
\begin{align}
v_{n+1}(x) =& \frac{du_n}{dx}(x), &
n=&0,1,2,\cdots &
\text{ for all } x \in D.
\tag{18}\label{18}
\end{align}
Using eqs. (\ref{16}) and (\ref{18}), we can rewrite eq. (\ref{10}) as
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,\epsilon) 
\sim& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{du_n}{dx}(x) \epsilon^n &
\text{ as } \epsilon\rightarrow&0+,
\tag{19}\label{19}
\end{align}
Herewith we demonstrated that the asymptotic expansion of $\partial u/\partial x$ ($=\partial^2 S/\partial x^2$) is in the form obtained by differentiating eq. (\ref{6a}) term by term.

Before moving on to deriving the asymptotic expansion of $S$, 
let us think about the meaning of eqs. (\ref{16}) and (\ref{18}).
Substituting eq. (\ref{11}) into eq. (\ref{16}), we obtain
\begin{equation}
[u_0(x)]^2 = Q(x),
\tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation}
or equivalently, 
\begin{equation}
u_0(x) = \pm [Q(x)]^{1/2}
\tag{21}\label{21}
\end{equation}
Substituting eq. (\ref{12}) into eq. (\ref{18}), we obtain
\begin{align}
U_{n+1}(x)
=& \frac{du_n}{dx}(x)  &
n=&0,1,2,\dots,
\tag{22}\label{22}
\end{align}
which can be rewritten with eq. (\ref{9}) as 
\begin{align}
\sum_{l=0}^{n+1} u_l(x) u_{n+1-l}(x)
=&\frac{du_n}{dx}(x),  &
n=&0,1,2,\cdots ,
\tag{23}\label{23}
\end{align}
or equivalently,
\begin{align}
u_{n+1}(x) 
=& \frac{1}{2 u_0(x)}\left\{ 
  -\sum_{l=1}^n  u_l(x) u_{n+1-l}(x)
 +\frac{du_n}{dx}(x)\right\},  &
n=&0,1,2,\cdots .
\tag{24}\label{24}
\end{align}
We can see that eqs. (\ref{21}) and (\ref{24}) determine the 
coefficients $\{u_n(x)\}$ of the asymptotic power series of $u(x,\epsilon)$ ($=\partial S/\partial x$) recursively.

Now let us consider the asymptotic expansion of $S(x,\epsilon)$.
From eq. (\ref{4a}), we have
\begin{equation}
S(b,\epsilon) -S(a,\epsilon) = \int_a^b dx u(x,\epsilon) ,
\tag{25}\label{25}
\end{equation}
for all $a$ and $b$ in $D$.
Since we are allowed integrate an asymptotic power series term by term,
from eq. (\ref{6a}), 
\begin{align}
\int_a^b dx u(x,\epsilon) 
\sim& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left[ \int_a^b dx u_n(x)\right] \epsilon^n &
\text{ as } \epsilon\rightarrow&0+,
\tag{26}\label{26}
\end{align}
for all $a$ and $b$ in $D$.
From eq. (\ref{25}) and (\ref{26}), we can say 
that $S(x,\epsilon)$ has an asymptotic power series,
\begin{align}
S(x,\epsilon) \sim& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} S_n(x) \epsilon^n &
\text{ as } \epsilon\rightarrow&0+,
\tag{27}\label{27}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
S_n(x) =& \int_a^x dt u_n(t)+S_n(a) , &
n=&0,1,2,\dots
\tag{28}\label{28}
\end{align}
for all $x$ and $a$ in $D$.
From eq. (\ref{28}), we can say
\begin{align}
u_n(x) =& \frac{dS_n}{dx}, &
n=&0,1,2,\dots
\tag{29}\label{29}
\end{align}
Herewith we confirmed that the assumption that $u(x,\epsilon)$ (=$\partial S/\partial x$) can be expanded in a uniform asymptotic power series implies that $S$ is also expanded in the asymptotic power series, 
and that the former asymptotic series 
is obtained by term-wise differentiation of the latter asymptotic series.

We can write eqs. (\ref{21}) and (\ref{24}) in terms of $\{S_n(x)\}$ as
\begin{equation}
\frac{dS_0}{dx} = \pm [Q(x)]^{1/2},
\tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{dS_{n+1}}{dx} 
=& \left[2 \frac{dS_0}{dx}\right]^{-1}\left\{ 
  -\sum_{l=1}^n  \frac{dS_l}{dx} \frac{dS_{n+1-l}}{dx}
 +\frac{d^2S_n}{dx^2}\right\},  &
n=&0,1,2,\cdots .
\tag{31}\label{31}
\end{align}
We see these equations [eqs. (\ref{30}) and (\ref{31})] in many textbooks explaining the WKB approximation.

So, in summary, by assuming the existence of the asymptotic power series for $\partial S/\partial x$, we can justify differentiating it term by term using the Ricatti equation, and we are guaranteed to have the asymptotic power series for $S$ whose term-wise differentiation gives the assumed asymptotic power series for $\partial S/\partial x$.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of asymptotic series, the `$\sim$'-symbol means the following:

Fix $N \in \mathbb{N}$. There exists a $\delta_0 > 0$ such that for all positive $\delta < \delta_0$, we have the equality
\begin{equation}
 S(x,\delta) = \sum_{n=0}^N s_n(x) \delta^n + \mathcal{O}(\delta^{N+1}), \tag{*}
\end{equation}
which is *uniformly* valid (i.e. for all $x$ in the domain in question).

If we can find a domain for $x$ and a $\delta_0>0$ such that the above holds for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$, then we use the notation
\begin{equation}
 S(x,\delta) \sim \sum_{n=0}^\infty s_n(x) \delta^n.
\end{equation}

Note that this not mean that the series converges in the classical sense. Moreover, we can add a term like $e^{-x/\delta}$ to the original function without changing the series approximation at any order. For more information on asymptotic series, see e.g.

F. Verhulst, *Methods and Applications of Singular Perturbations*, Springer, 2005.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used the symbol $\sim$ as you described in my question, and I have no problem with the definition of an asymptotic series. My question was: if you differentiate the series on the right hand side of your second equation term by term with respect to $x$, then is the resulting series asymptotic to $\partial S(x,\delta)/\partial x$?